# Find $\theta$ in the given triange

Tags: geometry, contest-math

[image: Triangle not drawn on scale]

Given an isosceles triangle ABC, AB=AC, AD=BC, angle ACB = 80 degree. What is $\theta$?

(I'm looking for ways to find this angle without using a calculator, sorry I added this late)

Comment: See [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/) for a discussion of various variations of this 80 degree isoceles triangle problem.

Comment: Oh the page you mentioned is interesting. Didn't know there are so many amazing properties with this type of triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\angle CBD$ be $\alpha$

Using the sine rule,

For $$\triangle CBD, \quad {BD\over \sin 80^\circ} = {BC \over \sin(100^\circ-\alpha)} \tag 1$$

For $$\triangle BDA,\quad  {BD \over \sin20^\circ} = {AD\over \sin\theta} \tag 2$$

Since $AD = BC$, we can take $(2) \over (1)$

This gives: $\displaystyle {{\sin(100-\alpha)\over \sin\theta} = \sin80^\circ \over \sin20^\circ}$

We know that $\theta = 80^\circ -\alpha$ because it is an isosceles triangle.

Therefore,  $${\sin(20^\circ+\theta)\over \sin\theta} = {\sin80^\circ \over \sin20^\circ}$$

Solving this gives us  $\theta = 10 ^{\circ}$

Comment: so how do I solve for $\theta$ if I don't have a calculator?